# A word that means cast aside and taken back repeatedly

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, etymology, synonyms

I need a word that defines that which is commonly tossed aside to be grabbed back again, like a notebook. I'm trying to use a word that defines this implicit nature in an object: something that is not that important, but at the same time is when you need to jot something down.

> Once a _____ notebook on which employers, directors, engineers, and visitors jotted down interesting events of the achievements of that time, has become the sacred book of The Company.

Comment: *on standby*, *at the ready*, that kind of thing?

Comment: A ***verb***? Please supply an example sentence with a blank for your word.

Comment: The Shop Book: once  a _____  notebook on which employers, directors, engineers, and visitors jotted down interesting events of the achievements of that time, has become the sacred book of The Company.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/316907/edit) to include that: comments are ephemeral. But it looks as though that should be an adjective (which might be formed from a past participle).

Comment: Any ideas on what word would fit? or maybe change the structure of the sentence to fit a more proper word.

Comment: Stop ignoring AndrewLeach's edit request and I'll stop ignoring your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it won't let me change it. It tells me that I need more credits or something. Show me how, I'm new to this page. Thanks!

Comment: You can always edit your own question (as you already have). Click on my link or the **edit** link under the tags, next to the red "edited" link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest ***occasional***:

> Once an ***occasional*** notebook used to jot down interesting events or achievements, it has now become a sacred book.

This is based in part that the notebook is used to record noteworthy occasions:

> **4**
>   :  acting in a specified capacity from time to time <an *occasional* lecturer>
>   **5**
>   :  designed or constructed to be used as the occasion demands <*occasional* furniture>
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasional)</sub>

Comment: I'm new to this. How can I approve your edit on my post?

Answer (score 1):

I like "insouciant" for this. It feels like "forgettable".

```
showing a casual lack of concern; indifferent.
```

Comment: Interesting word; its cognate in Spanish means to dirty something or soil it.

Comment: Oooh, I like that. That makes sense in that the OP indicated the notebook would be haphazardly cast aside.

Answer (score 0):

> A word that means cast aside and taken back repeatedly

I suggest

> **handy**
>
> ˈhandē
>
> adjective
>
> 1. convenient to handle or use; useful.
>      "a handy desktop encyclopedia"
>      "a handy reference tool"
>      synonyms:   *useful, convenient, practical, easy-to-use, well-designed, user-friendly, user-oriented, helpful, functional, serviceable*
> 2. close at hand.
>      "keep credit cards handy"
>      "keep your credit card handy"
>      synonyms:   *readily available, available, at hand, near at hand, within reach, accessible, ready, close, close by, near, nearby, at the ready, at one's fingertips; informalget-at-able*
>
> [google: handy define](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=handy%20define)

I suspect the 2nd definition is closer to your requested meaning though I don't think the 1st does your sentence a disservice.

> Once a **handy** notebook used to jot down interesting events or achievements, it has now become a sacred book.